# wpf font background in textbox

Tags: wpf, fonts, background, textbox

Is it possible to have a font background in a wpf textbox ?
I don't want to change the textbox background.
When the user enters text, the font background should be helpful to the user, e.g. to see a space character.
Problem:
If the textbox contains a space character only, you won't see it. It would be only noticed by the cursor, when it is focused.
How to set the FONT background (and NOT the TextBox background) in a wpf textbox ?

Comment: you may want to have a look at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742190.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a 2-coloured textbox background brush. The pixel width of the first color (font background) depends upon the text pixel width. The second color (white) fills the rest of the textbox background. The brush is created inside the textchanged event handler. Works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Fonts aren't visual objects in WPF, so there's no property on any of the font-related properties that will do what you'd like to do.  Instead, you should wrap your text in a Border object and place it in a container that will auto size it to the minimum size:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Orange" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBox>Text Goes Here</TextBox>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: <TextBox Background="Transparent">Text Goes Here</TextBox>

Comment: So in my case, i would add an editable TextBox. The auto-sizing works good, but if there's no characrer at all, you would always have a standard width with an orange background. This way you cannot differentiate between a space char, or an empty textbox.